# Chapter title in header too long

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, chapters

How can I format the header on every page displaying the title of the current chapter? In one of my chapters the title is too long so it is running out of the page.

Here's a minimal example of my document:

```
\documentclass[bibliography=totoc,version=first,listof=totoc,BCOR5mm,DIV12,index=totoc,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage{bibgerm}
\usepackage[english,german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\mainmatter
\chapter{Very long title}
\backmatter
\end{document}
```

Here's a screenshot of my problem:

[image]

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Another alternative might be:

```
\chapter[medium-length title for TOC, if wanted]{full title name}
\chaptermark{short title for running headers}
```

Comment: Great answer. For sections there is \sectionmark, but when using that, one might want to look at https://groups.google.com/g/comp.text.tex/c/ByM1hfL083Y.

Answer (score 18):

You could provide a shorter chapter title via the optional argument to `\chapter`:

```
\chapter[<short title>]{<long title>}
```

Note that this will also influence the entry in the table of contents.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I read this somewhere before... I think I have to leave the title as it is for the TOC :-/ is it a good idea to try a double line header?

Comment: @strauberry: You may have a look at [How can I display a short chapter name in the header and a long chapter name in the TOC](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/how-can-i-display-a-short-chapter-name-in-the-header-and-a-long-chapter-name-in-t).

Comment: @Stefan thank you for that hint, I used chaptermark now

Answer (score 6):

[The solution](http://pacinispace.blogspot.it/2015/06/long-titles-with-math-in-latex.html) that seems to work in every situation (even with math) is:

```
\chapter[\texorpdfstring{TOC title \( inline math A \)
    }{TOC in pdf bookmarks}
]{\chaptermark{header} Chapter title \( inline math A \)}
\chaptermark{header}
\label{CH:Chap}
```

In this solution the pdf bookmarks are defined by \texorpdfstring{#1}{#2}, where #1 is the title inside the pdf document while #2 is the pdf bookmark.

The [shorter] heading is defined by \chaptermark{header}. The repeated command is not a typo, but it is needed in order to have the right behaviour in every situation (do not ask why since I do not have any idea, just by tentative; if you know the reason, please comment. **EDIT (2016-03-22)**: Some explanations can be found [HERE](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-runheadtoobig.html))

**Important**: the solution also works with \section, just change \chaptermark with \sectionmark.

**Disclaimer**: I wrote the blog post.