# How to cut a section title in the header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, xstring

I redefine my headers as in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{monstyle}{%
\fancyhf{} % remove everything
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\rule[1.5ex]{\headwidth}{1pt}}
  \lhead{%
\leftmark%
  }
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{monstyle}
\section{le tres tres long titre qui prend trop de place sur la ligne}
\end{document}
```

The section title could be very long, like in my MWE, and i want to cut it at a fixed length (say 15 letters). My attempt is to use the command `\StrLeft` from the package `xstring` : I replace the line

```
\leftmark%
```

by

```
    \StrLeft{\leftmark}{15}...%
```

But i get compilation errors which i do not understand:

```
Argument of \@iiparbox has an extra }.
```

**EDIT**
I try to use Mico's solution, but i encounter now a problem with the TOC :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%% Redefine the short title
\let\origsection\section % 
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{% 
\def\ShortSecName{\StrLeft{#1}{10}...}
\origsection[\protect\ShortSecName]{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{mon titre tres long tres tres long}
\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext
\section{mon titre tres long tres tres long}
\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext
\end{document}
```

I get the error :

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

If i remove `\tableofcontents` then it compiles.

Comment: `\section` has an optional argument: `\section[Short Title]{Long title which is long}` The short version is what appears in headers, ToC etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chapter title in header too long](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26234/chapter-title-in-header-too-long)

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but i don't want to enter manually the "short title". I want to cut it automatically after n caraters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternative approach would be using `titleps` instead of `fancyhdr` (caveat: I'm the author of `titleps`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{titleps}

\newpagestyle{monstyle}{
   \headrule
   \sethead{\thepage}
           {}
           {\StrLeft{\sectiontitle}{15}...}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{monstyle}
\section{le tres tres long titre qui prend trop de place sur la ligne}
\end{document}
```

`\sectiontitle` is a macro containing just the title, not a mark with part of the header (formatted), and therefore it can be handled easily.

Comment: I added you as a package author in this thread: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/who-are-the-package-maintainers-here I guess this is ok for you.

Comment: @Thorsten. Of course it's ok. Thanx.

Comment: thanks for pointing out titlesep to me. I would have to learn the new syntaxe to try to reproduce the formatting i have in my "old" documents with fancyhdr... By the way, i'm already using titlesec... do i need titlesep as well, or can i do everything with titlesec ?

Comment: ok, i see, titleps works like an option of titlesec.

Comment: I tested your solution. I encouter problems with accented accents written directly `\section{ letters öäü}` (i use \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}). But it seems to be rather a problem of `\StrLeft`...

Comment: With `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, it solves the problem with accented letters.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to keep all the functionality of `\section` and get the original title in the table of contents, here is how

```
\makeatletter
\let\cutsec@ori@section\section
\def\section{\@ifstar\cutsec@ssection\cutsec@section}
\def\cutsec@ssection{\cutsec@ori@section*}
\def\cutsec@section{\@dblarg\cutsec@@section}
\def\cutsec@@section[#1]#2{%
  \cutsec@ori@section[#1]{#2}%
  \StrLeft{#2}{10}[\temp]%
  \expandafter\markboth{\expandafter\MakeUppercase\expandafter{\temp...}}{}}
\makeatother
```

However, such a way of doing is risky when the section title has accented characters, unless you use an 8 bit encoding (latin-1, for instance) and refrain from explicit accents such as `` \'el\`eve ``, that is, you write `élève`. It's definitely bound to break with UTF-8 and `pdflatex` (not with UTF-8 engines such as XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX).

Comment: Great answer! About accents and related diacritics in the section header: I believe that as long you place the diacritics and their associated characters within curly braces -- e.g., {\'e}l{\`e}ve and L{\"o}ffel -- you'll be safe even when running this code under pdflatex.

Comment: @Mico Yes, but you lose kerning.

Answer (score 6):

You need to `\protect` the `\StrLeft` command. You don't explain what exactly you do with redefining the `\leftmark` command, so I suggest you use the `\protect\StrLeft` approach in the setup of the `\section[]{}` command:

```
\section[\protect\StrLeft{Le tres tres long titre qui prend 
  trop de place sur la ligne}{15}]{Le tres tres long titre 
  qui prend trop de place sur la ligne}
```

**Addendum** One can automate this process by redefining the `\section` command suitably, say along the lines of the following MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xstring,fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{monstyle}{%
  \fancyhf{} % remove everything
  \renewcommand{\headrule}{\rule[1.5ex]{\headwidth}{1.2pt}}
  \lhead{\leftmark}
  }
\pagestyle{monstyle}  

\let\origsection\section       %  Save the original \section command
\renewcommand{\section}[2][15]{%  Default value for the first, optional arg: "15"
    \origsection[\protect\StrLeft{#2}{#1}]{#2}}
\begin{document}

\section[23]{Le tr{\`e}s tr{\`e}s long titre qui prend trop de place sur la ligne}

Il y avait une fois que \ldots
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the redefined `\section` command takes *two* arguments. The first argument, the number of characters to be retained for the short title or running head, is *optional* and defaults to 15. The second argument is the "regular" (possibly very long) section header. If you don't want *any* shortening of the section header, just supply a number -- is 1,000 large enough? -- that exceeds the number of characters in the section header.

*Notes*: (i) Should you need to create a section header *without* automatically setting the page's running head as well, you could use the command `\origsection` (which contains, unsurprisingly, the original version of the `\section` command). (ii) A side effect of this setup is that the `\tableofcontents` and `\section*` commands won't work correctly; let me know if this is a concern to you, and I'll figure out a solution.

Comment: it sounds interesting. It indeed works, if i declare the short title in `\section`, but this is not what i want to do. I want that for all sections automatically, and not enter `StrLeft{my short title}{15}` per hand... otherwise, i could cut it directly per hand. So, how could i use `\protect` inside the fancyhdr declaration ?

Comment: Please see the addendum I've provided. I don't believe your issue can be solved by modifying the fancyhdr macros. Instead, what's needed -- if I understand your objectives, of course -- is a redefinition of the `\section` command.

Comment: I tested your solution, but it makes a problem with the TOC. Please see my edit (in 5 minutes).

Comment: by the way, yes, you are probably right, it is much more logical to redefine the short title than the fancyhdr macros.

Comment: yes, actually, i need the TOC. By the way, the first argument [15] could be hard-coded if it helps, and the command `\section` would stay with the same structure `\section[short]{long title}`, where the 1st argument wouldnt be used in my case.

Comment: I recommend you adopt the solution that @egreg has already provided. After looking at my code and his code for a while, I've come to the conclusion that if I were to change my code to make it compatible with the `\tableofcontents` command, it would have to end up looking virtually like his. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`truncate`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/truncate) package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[breakall]{truncate}
\fancypagestyle{monstyle}{%
\fancyhf{} % remove everything

\renewcommand{\headrule}{\rule[1.5ex]{\headwidth}{1pt}}
\lhead{\truncate{15em}{\leftmark}}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{monstyle}
\section{le tres tres long titre qui prend trop de place sur la ligne}
\end{document}
```

[image]