# How to cut chapter title in header using xstring

Tags: header-footer, xstring

I need to cut the chapter title that appears at page headers.

I'm developing a latex generator software (http://github.com/caelum/tubaina, new contributors are welcome!), and because of implementation issues I can't simply use `\chaptermark` to create an arbitrary title for the header. I've tried using `\StrLeft` from `xstring` but didn't work for me.

Here is the latex code that produces the output that I would like to see, but in a way I can't use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\footnotesize{Publisher Name}}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\scriptsize{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\scriptsize{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
    \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
}

\pagestyle{plain}

%% This doesn't work
% \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ \StrLeft{#1}{5}}{}}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}{}}

\chapter{Very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long chapter title}

%% This also doesn't work
% \chaptermark{\StrLeft{chapter mark lalala lalala}{5}}

%% This works and that's the way I would like to the 
%% title appear, but I can't use it for other reasons...
\chaptermark{Very long long...}

\section{Section name}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Is there any another way to do that?

Comment: See for example [How to cut a section title in the header](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-to-cut-a-section-title-in-the-header)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fragile command in moving argument so you could use

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ \protect\StrLeft{#1}{5}}{}}
```

Although rather than chopping off after so many characters I think a better result could be obtained by typesetting to a specified measure into a temporary box, and then just showing the first line.

---

Something like this implements the scheme sketched above:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\footnotesize Publisher Name}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\scriptsize\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\scriptsize\chopheader{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
    \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
}

\pagestyle{plain}

\makeatletter
\def\chopheader#1{{%
\hbadness\@M
\vbadness\@M
  \setbox\z@\vbox{%
\hsize=0.3\textwidth
\@parboxrestore\raggedright
\interlinepenalty-\@M
#1}%
\setbox\tw@\vsplit\z@ to \baselineskip
\setbox\tw@\vbox{\unvbox\tw@\global\setbox\@ne\lastbox}%
\leavevmode\unhbox\@ne\unskip\unskip\ifdim\ht\z@>\z@\ldots\fi
}}
\makeatother

%% This doesn't work
% \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ \protect\StrLeft{#1}{5}}{}}

%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}{}}

\chapter{Very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long chapter title}

%% This also doesn't work
% \chaptermark{\StrLeft{chapter mark lalala lalala}{5}}

%% This works and that's the way I would like to the 
%% title appear, but I can't use it for other reasons...
%\chaptermark{Very long long...}

\section{Section name}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks! It seems to be the most elegant solution!

Comment: I just added a \hfill to align the chapter title to right, like this: \fancyhead[RO]{\hfill\scriptsize\chopheader{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}

Comment: Is there a way to show a ellipsis in case the title overflow the vbox? Resulting in something like: "Very long long..."

Comment: The `\hfill` shouldn't be necessary the RO option to fancyheader should do that I think, as shown in my image? adding an elipsis change one line so it looks like `\leavevmode\unhbox\@ne\unskip\ifdim\ht\z@>\z@\ldots\fi`

Comment: Thanks again, it worked! Strange, without `hfill` the title didn't got aligned rigth, see this image [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2682197/header.png)

Comment: sorry that was a bug: if the heading was short you got rightskip _and_ parfillskip that needs removing so there has to be two `\unskip` I edited the answer (and added the `\ldots` test at the same time)

Answer (score 3):

The expansion of some `xstring` macros are not purely expandable, as explained in the [documentation](http://ftp.roedu.net/mirrors/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xstring/xstring_doc_en.pdf) - section *3.2 Expansion of macros, optional argument*. That's why the author supplied them with an optional argument, to store the result. You can modify your code to make it work, like this for instance:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\StrLeft{#1}{5}[\shortTitle]%
\markboth{\thechapter.\ \shortTitle}{}}
```

Comment: This should work but David Carlisle solution above seems to be the most elegant one... Thanks anyway!

Comment: It is, indeed. `:)`