# Printing just the first 20 characters of a text, adding \ldots

Tags: text-manipulation

Is it possible to truncate the name of a chapter to - let's say - 20 characters and adding `\ldots` to it? So that it fits into the space of the tabs shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181081/clickable-chapters-on-the-right-side-of-each-page)?

Comment: Related: [Truncate text from right to left](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174554/5764)

Comment: Also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-to-cut-a-section-title-in-the-header/48048#48048

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I mean that better than to set fixed number of characters is to set the maximal dimension of printed text. I suggest the macro `\striptext to dimen {text}` which outputs the text in the macro `\striptextout`. The text in `\striptextout` fits to the hypothetical box of the given width. Other characters (if they exist) are ignored.

For example `\striptext to2cm {foo foo bar bar}` defines `\striptextout` as a macro `foo foo bar b`. Or `\striptext to1cm {foo foo bar bar}` outputs to `foo fo`. Or `\striptext to30cm {foo foo bar bar}` behaves like `\def\striptextout{foo foo bar bar}`.

```
\def\striptext to#1 #2{\def\striptextout{}\def\tmp{#1}\striptextA #2\relax\end}
\def\striptextA{\futurelet\next\striptextB}
\def\striptextB{\ifx\next\relax \expandafter \skiptoend
   \else \ifx\next\spacetoken
             \edef\striptextoutA{\striptextout\space}%
             \def\next{\afterassignment\striptextD \let\next= }%
         \else \def\next{\striptextC}%
   \fi   \fi
   \next
}
\def\striptextC#1{\edef\striptextoutA{\striptextout#1}\striptextD}
\def\striptextD{\setbox0=\hbox{\striptextoutA}%
   \ifdim\wd0>\tmp\relax \expandafter \skiptoend
   \else \let\striptextout=\striptextoutA \expandafter \striptextA
   \fi
}
\def\skiptoend#1\end{}
\edef\tmp{\let\noexpand\spacetoken= \space}\tmp

\striptext to1cm {foo foo bar bar}
\message{:::: \striptextout}

\bye
```

How it works: We need to get token per token from given text, cummulate it to `\striptextout` and do the measurement of the text in `\striptextout` repeatedly. The main problem is that TeX cannot simply get the space to the parameter `#1`. This is the rason why the macro is more complicated. First we test by `\futurelet\next` if the `\next` is space token. If it is true then we need to remove spacetoken from input stream by `\let\next=` (watch the space after equal sign, this first space is ignored by `\let` primitive and second space is taken from input stream). After `\let` is done the measurement in `\striptextD` is processed. The given width is stored in the `\tmp` macro.
If the next token isn't spacetoken then this token is normaly taken by `#1` of `\striptextC`. The masurement in `\striptextD` is processed ordinarily: the text is stored to `\box0` and width `\wd0` is compared with `\tmp`. The `\relax` here is important because expansion of `\ifdim` condition have to be closed before next `\expandafter`. The loop is repeated here by next call of `\striptextoutA`.
The `\striptoend` macro ignores the rest of input stream to the `\end` separator. This is executed when we are finished.

Notice about the usage of `\striptext`: the space after dimen and before `{text}` is required. If you need to make more common macro (without `to` clause) in the form

```
\striptext{dimen}{text}
```

then simply write `\def\striptext#1#2{...}` (without space between `#1` and `#2`.

Comment: @ wipet: Thanks a lot for this macro! This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

ConTeXt provides two macros to achieve this.

1. `\doboundtext`
2. `\limitatetext`

The user interface of both commands is:

```
\command {text to be limited} {width} {append}
```

where the first argument can be arbitrary TeX code, the second argument can be arbitrary TeX dimen, and the third argument can be arbitrary TeX code.

The `\doboundtext` macro is similar to the `\striptex` macro defined by @wipet; it typesets the content in a box, and then truncates the box. A drawback of this approach is that the text does not hyphenate.

The `\limitatetext` macro is more robust and allows for the text to break across lines. It also when reading the file, for example

```
\limitatetext{\input ward \relax}{6cm}{\unknown}
```

gives

[image]

The `\limitatetext` has another version, that allows you to pick some material from the end as well. For example:

```
\limitatetext{\input ward \relax}{6cm,2cm}{\unknown}
```

gives

[image]

See [supp-box.mkiv](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/refs/heads/origin:/tex/context/base/supp-box.mkiv#l1154) for implementation details.

Comment: @ Aditya; Thanks a lot. I like the the feature picking also the end of the text and will have a try to implement this in PDFLaTex