# How to make (force) line-break in Chapter Title (in ToC, Chapter, Header) - if possible?

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, header-footer, line-breaking, chapters

I've found how to make different text for Title appearing in ToC, Chapter and headers [Chapter title in header too long](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26234/chapter-title-in-header-too-long) :

```
\chapter[medium-length title for TOC, if wanted]{full title name}
\chaptermark{short title for running headers}
```

How to make ("force") line-break (if possible) in each of those three titles:

- in ToC
- in Chapter
- in Header

?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The standard class page headers are really only set up for one line. If doing it a lot you should modify the page headers to set the mark text into a parbox, but for a one-off long entry you can put the parbox into the mark. So this breaks all three instances:

```
\chapter[medium-length\\ title for TOC, if wanted]{full\\ title name}
\chaptermark{\protect\parbox{.5\textwidth}{short title\\ for running headers}}
```