# Is there method for removing \\ newlines - problem with fancyhdr and multiline chapter name

Tags: header-footer, line-breaking, chapters, fancyhdr

Some of my chapter has very long names, and they have different break line in ToC and on Chapter page, according to [a solution to *How to make (force) line-break in Chapter Title (in ToC, Chapter, Header) - if possible?*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43435/7128)

The problem is that when I have such "multi-line" chapter name, it is broken in `fancyhdr`.

(For clarification : new lines are problem in `fancydhr`. In ToC and chapter names they  are intentional and have to stay)

Is there a method for removing newlines `\\`, like `\MakeUppercase` for making letters uppercase ?

```
\documentclass[pdftex,a4paper,12pt,twoside,openany]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{8pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newcommand{\term}{\textit}
%\cleardoublepage \phantomsection
\chapter
[FIRST LONG LINE\\SECOND \textit{LONG} LINE\\THIRD LONG LINE\\FOURTH LONG LINE]
{FIRST LONG LINE\\SECOND \textit{LONG} LINE\\THIRD LONG LINE\\FOURTH LONG LINE}
\lipsum[1-60]
\end{document}
```

What I am looking for is a kind of macro `\MakeNoNewlines` that would be used in similar fashion as `\MakeUppercase:` is used :

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ \MakeNoNewlines{#1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ \MakeNoNewlines{#1}}}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example showing at least one chapter that has a ToC and the headline. This should also load the necessary `\documentclass`.

Comment: @Werner - Thanks, I alsways try to provide such. Yesterday I've been running out of time. Question updated with minimal example.

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki Such long titles won't fit in the header anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Your `\MakeNoNewlines` command can be defined as in the following. We can locally redefine `\\` to insert only a `<space>`. It doesn't help for the Table of contents though.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openany]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{8pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ \MakeNoNewlines{#1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ \MakeNoNewlines{#1}}}

\def\MakeNoNewlines#1{\begingroup\def\\{ }#1\endgroup} % <-- here

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newcommand{\term}{\textit}
%\cleardoublepage \phantomsection
\chapter
[FIRST LONG LINE\\SECOND LONG LINE\\THIRD LONG LINE\\FOURTH LONG LINE]
{FIRST LONG LINE\\SECOND LONG LINE\\THIRD LONG LINE\\FOURTH LONG LINE}
\lipsum[1-60]
\end{document}
```

Comment: newlines in ToC are fine. They are only problem in fancyhdr. In first free moment I will checkout your solution with my document.

Comment: It does not work in my case, as there are `\textit{}` in my chapter and section names. This results in error: `Use of \protect doesn't match its definition.` . I've updated MWE.