# Classicthesis short title not appear in Table of Content in LYX

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx, classicthesis

I'm writting my thesis with the `classicalthesis` package. I have a problem with long chapter titles being too long for headings. For that reason I use  the short title option (in Lyx). By definition the short titles are used for the Table of Content but I want them to be long in the TOC. I read

http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=14166

and I used the `titlesec` package with the "toctitles" option in the (LaTeX) preamble in LyX, but I get an error message form Lyx:

> LaTeX Error: Option clash for package titlesec. Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.

Sorry I dont know how to attach example files in my question, I attach two pictures: 
[image: Long and short title Chapter]
[image: PDF generate] Please see the content list

Comment: I do not use LyX, but if you are able to edit the TeX source, you should read http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6862 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26234

Comment: How to do this depends on the document class in use. There recommended (by the package author) class is of the KOMA bundle. You can define  a title for the document, one for the running header and one for the toc. `titlesec` should not be used with KOMA. To sum it up: We need a [compilable example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html) to play with.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem in the following way:

I inserted the following Tex code in Lyx:

```
\stepcounter{chapter} 
\chaptermark{SHORT TITLE} 
\addtocounter{chapter}{-1} 
\chapter{VERY VERY VERY VERY LONG TITLE} 
\chaptermark{SHORT TITLE}
```

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).