# How to set rightmark after \section command?

Tags: sectioning, header-footer

I need to typset a book with very long section names. The long names should appear in the normal text and in the ToC but not in the header, so I can’t use the optional argument.
`\sectionmark` is my fried but only for the page after the `\section` started because the first marking command on a page wins the place in the header.

Is it possible to set the header of the current page even after a `\section` set a header already?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Test}
    \lipsum
    \section{A Section}
    \lipsum[3-5]
    \section{A very long section title, which doesn't
             fit in the header because it's extremly long}
    \sectionmark{Short title}
    \lipsum[1-14]
\end{document}
```

The example is very minimalistic. The template I must use uses `fancyhdr` to change the layout.

---

I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/how-can-i-display-a-short-chapter-name-in-the-header-and-a-long-chapter-name-in) answer but it works only for chaperts because they always happen to be on a right page and so `\chaptermark` gives the desired result on the next left page.

---

### Follow up question to my answer

Is ist possible to make a (Perl or whatever running on Mac OS X) script that converts

```
\section{long text}
\sectionmark{short text}
```

to

```
\section[long text]{long text\sectionmark{short text}}
```

or alternatively to

```
\section{long text}[short text]
```

I can’t ensure that there are no line breaks in the `long text` or if there is a break between `\section` and `\sectionmark`.

I asked the follow up question again [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9096695/1018250) on StackOverflow.

Comment: Your second approach works for me and produces the desired result.

Comment: Actually, you should turn your second approach into an answer. You'd have my upvote. ;-)

Comment: the **Update:** variant works for me too I think.

Comment: @lockstep: I forgot to delete the aux files O:-) But I wonder if there would be another method because the book is finished and it would be great if I don’t have to change the whole code manually …

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A possibility is to have a syntax such as

```
\section[toc entry]{title}[header entry]
```

that is similar to yours. Here's a way:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse,lipsum}

\makeatletter
\let\tobi@kept@section\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s}
  {\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\tobi@kept@ssection*}{\tobi@section}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\tobi@section}{o m o}
  {\IfNoValueTF{#3}% No short title for the header
     {\IfNoValueTF{#1}% No title for the toc
        {\tobi@kept@section{#2}}
        {\tobi@kept@section[#1]{#2}}%
     }
     {\IfNoValueTF{#1}% No title for the toc
        {\tobi@kept@section[#2]{#2\sectionmark{#3}}\sectionmark{#3}}
        {\tobi@kept@section[#1]{#2\sectionmark{#3}}\sectionmark{#3}}%
    }%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum

\section{A Section}

\lipsum[3-5]

\section
  [A very long section title, which doesn't fit
   in the header because it's extremely long]
  {A very long section title, which doesn't fit\\
   in the header because it's extremly long}[Short title]

\lipsum[1-12]

\section
  {A very long section title, which doesn't fit
   in the header because it's extremly long}[Short title, but longer]

\lipsum[1-14]

\end{document}
```

The approach of `memoir` is

```
\section[toc entry][header entry]{title}
```

but I prefer to have later the header entry (it's also easier to realize it with `xparse`).

Comment: Very nice approach. I thought about something similar simpler but less robust …

Comment: Why does section[X]{X\sectionmark{Y}}
\sectionmark{Y} 
work but 
section{X\sectionmark{Y}}
\sectionmark{Y} 
doesn't?

Comment: @gghuffer Because the mark has to be issued twice in order to comply with the request.

Answer (score 8):

I found an approach [here](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-runheadtoobig) (vie the linked page). Seems to work but I wonder if there is a way without changing my code?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Test}
    \lipsum
    \section{A Section}
    \lipsum[3-5]
    \section[% necessary to keep \sectionmark away from ToC
        A very long section title, which doesn't fit in
        the header because it's extremly long
    ]{%
        A very long section title, which doesn't fit in
        the header because it's extremly long%
        \sectionmark{Short title}% changes the head for the current page
    }
    \sectionmark{Short title}% changes the head for following pages
    \lipsum[1-14]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

If using `titlesec` is possible, just write:

```
\usepackage[toctitles]{titlesec}
```

With that, the optional argument in sectioning commands only is used for the header, while for the TOC entry the full title is used.

Comment: Didn’t know that. Thanks. But I can’t use `titlesec` :-( furthermor your approche needs also a change of my code …

Answer (score 0):

In KOMA-Script it is now possible to use a keyval list as optional argument for `\section` etc. to set the ToC entry and page head differently. First one must activate this by using `headings = optiontoheadandtoc|optiontohead|optiontotoc` as class option:

- `optiontoheadandtoc`: same as default behavior, i.e. the optional argument is used for ToC and head mark, but the optional keyval syntax is enabled.
- `optiontohead`: optional argument is only used for the head mark (and the optional keyval syntax is enabled)
- `optiontotoc`: optional argument is only used for ToC (and the optional keyval syntax is enabled)

With the optional keyval syntax one *can* use `head={head mark}` and/or `tocentry={toc}`:

```
\documentclass[%
   headings = optiontoheadandtoc,% or 'optiontohead' or 'optiontotoc'
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Headline}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter[ToC and Page Head]{Headline}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter[tocentry={ToC}]{Headline}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter[head={Page Head}]{Headline}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter[tocentry={ToC},head={Page Head}]{Headline}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```