# Separate sectioning titles for main text, headings, and toc for line breaking purposes

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, header-footer, line-breaking, titlesec

I am using the [titlesec](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package with the `toctitles` option, which modifies the optional argument of sectioning commands so that this optional argument is used only in headings; the non-optional argument is then used in both the main text and the table of contents. Not using the `toctitles` option would lead to the optional argument to also be used in the table of contents.

I need to have different arguments for each of the three targets: main text, headings, and table of contents. Is this possible? The reason for this is that I need different line breaks in the main text and in the table of contents, and I need to be able to specify different text for the headings. In case there are line-breaking commands that are context-aware (toc vs. main text), those would provide an alternative solution.

Comment: By any chance, are you using a KOMA-class? This functionality is built in there.

Comment: @Johannes_B: No, and this is a big project, effectively too big to switch to KOMA.

Comment: Can you prepare a [minimal working example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html)+ This means showing us the documentclass, and everything to understand the topic.

Comment: Related: [How to set `\rightmark` after `\section` command?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42981/5764) (suggestion there implements `\section[<toc entry>]{<title>}[<header entry>]` *without* [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec))

Comment: @Johannes_B: Can you point to the functionality of KOMA-Script regarding the question above? I have the same question, and are using `scrbook`. I´ve been reading the manual, but are not sure what to look for.

Comment: @Kubo Search for `optiontoheadandtoc` in the manual. The very specific thing you are looking for is an example on page 96 (at least 96 in my version of the manual).

Comment: @Johannes_B: Wow, hit the nail on the head. Here is a solution for `KOMA`: `\chapter[head={A normal chapter heading ...}, tocentry={A normal chapter-heading, which is a little bit to long \newline but can be broken here for the ToC}]{A normal chapter-heading, which is a little bit to long, but nothing is done to it here.}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can insert an additional optional argument that allows for separately specifying a ToC/header/title of a `\section`.

The original definition of `\ttl@straight@i` (called by a sectional unit under the `straight` - default - class) looks like this:

```
\def\ttl@straight@i#1[#2]#3{%
  \def\@currentlabelname{#2}% for nameref
  \gdef\ttl@savemark{\csname#1mark\endcsname{#3}}%
  \let\ttl@savewrite\@empty
  \def\ttl@savetitle{#3}%
  \gdef\thetitle{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
  \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
  \par
  \ttl@labelling{#1}{#2}%
  \ttl@startargs\ttl@straight@ii{#1}{#3}}
```

It takes 3 arguments and based on the way it is processed by [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec), all of them are mandatory (but may be empty). We can insert a truly optional argument inbetween using some help from [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse):

```
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\ttl@straight@i}{m R[]{} o m}{%
  \def\@currentlabelname{#2}% for nameref
  \gdef\ttl@savemark{\csname#1mark\endcsname{#4}}%
  \let\ttl@savewrite\@empty
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}
    {\def\ttl@savetitle{#4}}% Optional #3 argument NOT supplied
    {\def\ttl@savetitle{#3}}% Optional #3 argument supplied
  \gdef\thetitle{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
  \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
  \par
  \ttl@labelling{#1}{#2}%
  \ttl@startargs\ttl@straight@ii{#1}{#4}}
\makeatother
```

The argument `R[]{}` is a required argument delimited by `[`..`]` with an empty `{}` default; `O{}` would work just as well here. However, the inclusion of `o` now allows us to use either of the following:

- `\section[<header>][<ToC>]{<title>}`
- `\section[<header>]{<ToC-and-title>}`
- `\section{<header-ToC-and-title>}`

We only have to condition on what to store in `\ttl@savetitle` based on whether or not `[<ToC>]` was supplied.

Here is a complete, minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=a6paper]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage[pagestyles,toctitles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newpagestyle{main}{ 
  \headrule% Include a rule
  \sethead{\thesection.~\sectiontitle}% Left header
          {}                          % Center header
          {\normalsize \thepage}      % Right header
}
\pagestyle{main}

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\ttl@straight@i}{m R[]{} o m}{%
  \def\@currentlabelname{#2}% for nameref
  \gdef\ttl@savemark{\csname#1mark\endcsname{#4}}%
  \let\ttl@savewrite\@empty
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}
    {\def\ttl@savetitle{#4}}% Optional #3 argument NOT supplied
    {\def\ttl@savetitle{#3}}% Optional #3 argument supplied
  \gdef\thetitle{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
  \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
  \par
  \ttl@labelling{#1}{#2}%
  \ttl@startargs\ttl@straight@ii{#1}{#4}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section[fIrst sEctIOn][FiRST SeCTioN]{First section}
\clearpage
\section[sEcOnd sEctIOn]{Second section}
\clearpage
\section{Third section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What would I need to change to get `\section[<ToC>][<header>]{<title>}` and `\section[<ToC>]{<header-and-title>}`?

Comment: To answer the question in my own comment above: first exchange `#2` and `#3` and then replace all occurrences of `#3` by `\IfNoValueTF{#3}{#4}{#3}`. To make things explicit, after this exchange, `#1` corresponds to the section level, `#2` to the optional `<ToC>`, `#3` to the optional `<header>`, and `#4` to the mandatory `<title>`, which is also used for `<header>` if the second optional argument is omitted or for `<ToC>` `<header>` if both optional arguments are omitted.