# titlesec: how to access to the optional argument of the \chapter macro for ToC inputs?

Tags: titlesec, titletoc

For different treatments, I need to have two independent main files for tables of contents using the `titlesec`/`titletoc` packages (I already use partial ToCs with the .ptc file).

In order to write the ToC-titles entries of sections in these two files, one can simply redefine the `\ttl@addcontentsline` macro from the `titlesec` package (see MWE), but this does not work for chapters.

Following the egreg's advice (somewhere here), I don't use the explicit option and I define separately the layout macros. So, I'm able to add a ToC line for chapters, but this can be done only with the mandatory argument.

For further formatting purposes, I need to access to the optional argument of the `\chapter[<ToC-title>]{<Title>}`. The internal mechanisms of the `titlesec` package are too obscure for me (shy tiny beginner with the internals) and I failed (are the `\ttl@top@i`, `\ttl@top@ii` and/or `\ttl@select` macros have to be considered here?).

Moreover however (may be another question?), I'm aware of the possibility to add more optional arguments to sectioning commands with `titlesec` ([Separate sectioning titles for main text, headings, and toc for line breaking purposes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150561/)), like having different headers (commented code below). Is this could be achieved for chapters too in order to have something like `\chapter[<ToC-title>]{<Title>}[<Header-title>]`? (cf. [How to set rightmark after \section command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42981/how-to-set-rightmark-after-section-command))

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,a4paper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}
%\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\def\ttl@addcontentsline#1#2{% From titlesec: Works for sections but not for chapters
    \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{\ifttl@toclabel\ttl@a\fi#2}%
    \addcontentsline{tdm}{#1}{\ifttl@toclabel\ttl@a\fi#2}%
    \nobreak}

\newcommand\secondtableofcontents{% From book.cls
    \if@twocolumn
        \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
        \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname \ two
        \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{tdm}% TDM stands for "Table des matières" in French
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }

%\RenewDocumentCommand{\ttl@straight@i}{m R[]{} o m}{%
%  \def\@currentlabelname{#2}% for nameref
%  \gdef\ttl@savemark{\csname#1mark\endcsname{#4}}%
%  \let\ttl@savewrite\@empty
%  \IfNoValueTF{#3}
%    {\def\ttl@savetitle{#4}}% Optional #3 argument NOT supplied
%    {\def\ttl@savetitle{#3}}% Optional #3 argument supplied
%  \gdef\thetitle{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
%  \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
%  \par
%  \ttl@labelling{#1}{#2}%
%  \ttl@startargs\ttl@straight@ii{#1}{#4}}
\makeatother

% Layout commands
\newcommand{\numberedChapterLayout}[1]{% Original complex code
    \Huge\bfseries #1
    \addcontentsline{tdm}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}\protect#1}
}
\newcommand{\numberlessChapterLayout}[1]{% Original complex code
    \Huge\bfseries #1}
\newcommand{\sectionLayout}[1]{\Large\bfseries #1}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}{}{0pt}{\numberedChapterLayout}[]
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]{}{}{0pt}{\numberlessChapterLayout}[]
\titleformat{\section}
  [hang]{}{\thesection}{16pt}{\sectionLayout}% #1 implicit
  []% after the title body

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\secondtableofcontents

\chapter[First chapter title]{Title of the first chapter}
\section[Section A]{Section A, first chapter}
\section[Section B]{Section B, first chapter}

\chapter[Second chapter title]{Title of the second chapter}
\section[Section A]{Section A, second chapter}
\section[Section B]{Section B, second chapter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: try `\let\oldaddcontentsline\addcontentsline
\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{%
\def\tmp{toc}\def\ttmp{#1}%
\oldaddcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}%
\ifx\tmp\ttmp
\oldaddcontentsline{tdm}{#2}{#3}%
\fi}` instead of `\def\ttl@addcontentsline...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of redefine `\ttl@addcontentsline` one can redefine the original `\addcontentsline`

```
\let\oldaddcontentsline\addcontentsline
\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{%
\oldaddcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}%
\def\tmp{toc}\def\ttmp{#1}%
\ifx\tmp\ttmp
\oldaddcontentsline{tdm}{#2}{#3}%
\fi}
```

this way it work for chapters and sections.

2) One can patch `\@chapter` command to acces

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\@chapter{\chaptermark{#1}}{\chaptermark{#1}\def\@currentlabelname{#1}}{}{}
```

---

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,a4paper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}
%\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}

\let\oldaddcontentsline\addcontentsline
\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{%
\def\tmp{toc}\def\ttmp{#1}%
\oldaddcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}%
\ifx\tmp\ttmp
\oldaddcontentsline{tdm}{#2}{#3}%
\fi}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\secondtableofcontents{% From book.cls
    \if@twocolumn
        \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
        \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname \ two
        \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{tdm}% TDM stands for "Table des matières" in French
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
\makeatother

% Layout commands
\newcommand{\numberedChapterLayout}[1]{% Original complex code
    \Huge\bfseries #1
    %\addcontentsline{tdm}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}\protect#1}
}
\newcommand{\numberlessChapterLayout}[1]{% Original complex code
    \Huge\bfseries #1}
\newcommand{\sectionLayout}[1]{\Large\bfseries #1}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}{}{0pt}{\numberedChapterLayout}[]
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]{}{}{0pt}{\numberlessChapterLayout}[]
\titleformat{\section}
  [hang]{}{\thesection}{16pt}{\sectionLayout}% #1 implicit
  []% after the title body

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\secondtableofcontents

\chapter[First chapter title]{Title of the first chapter}
\section[Section A]{Section A, first chapter}
\section[Section B]{Section B, first chapter}

\chapter[Second chapter title]{Title of the second chapter}
\section[Section A]{Section A, second chapter}
\section[Section B]{Section B, second chapter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. That works fine with the MWE, but still not with my real case for the moment. I have to investigate more in deep... Thanks also for the macro to patch (it was relatively logical...)

Comment: @ejazz you're welcome :-). I am sorry i can't answer what i can not see. You should know that `titlesec` changes only `makechapterhead`

Comment: After verification, your solution works very efficiently (silly I am: an obvious wrong placement of macros with `hyperref`). So, fully accepted! Thanks again.