# chapter title on two lines in the TOC

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, header-footer, chapters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I display a short chapter name in the header and a long chapter name in the ToC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/how-can-i-display-a-short-chapter-name-in-the-header-and-a-long-chapter-name-in)

I have a quite long chapter title that I break into two lines as follows:

```
\chapter{long \newline title}
```

This works well for the title in itself and how it is shown in the table of contents. The problem lies in the header where the title become `longtitle` (no space between the two words). Would there be an easy way to solve this? I was thinking of using the optional field of the `\chapter` command but it will also modify what is shown in the TOC (which I am so far happy with).

Comment: does this answer help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/how-can-i-display-a-short-chapter-name-in-the-header-and-a-long-chapter-name-in

Comment: Nice. My question is probably a duplicate then. I could not find this post when I was searching in the database.