# Chapter name overrunning page

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, chapters

I am editing a collection of documents, a few of which the author has given such long titles that, when they are formatted as chapters, the heading overruns the page.  The following code should suffice to reproduce this situation:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{book} % 12pt is a manuscript requirement.
% I am using the following three packages with pdflatex.
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[top=3.0in,head=2.0in,inner=2.0in,outer=1.0in,bottom=1.0in,nofoot]{geometry} % Manuscript requirement.
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % Manuscript requirement.
\usepackage{microtype} % Provides ligature disabling in pdflatex (manuscript requirement) among other things.
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e} % Manuscript requirement.
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace} % Manuscript requirement.
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tgheros} % The font that I intend to use.
\sloppy % Helps package hyphenat.
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding=T1} % Manuscript requirement.
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{german}
\renewcommand*{\chaptername}{\textnumero{}}
\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{592}
\chapter{>>Kleiner Ärger -- vom Mantel der Zufriedenheit überdeckt<< (Beweise für die Unmenschlichkeit und Verlogenheit der >>Arbeiter<<-Annonce in >>Welt<< und >>Spiegel<<) (von~Schnitzler, 2.~August~1971)}
\textlangle{}Text\textrangle{}
\end{document}
```

Obnoxious in more ways than one, no?

In this situation I would prefer to break the heading to the next page at the bottom margin.  Does anyone have ideas on how to do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  the answers to this question cover this situation:  [How can I display a short chapter name in the header and a long chapter name in the ToC?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6862/579)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the rather strict formatting-related requirements you need to satisfy, the only two free parameters you can vary sensibly for the chapter header page are (i) the amount of additional vertical space inserted *above* the chapter number (default: `50pt`) and (ii) the amount of additional vertical space inserted *between* the chapter number line and the line(s) containing the chapter title itself (default: `20pt`). The following code uses the command `\patchcmd` of the `etoolbox` package to set these parameters to `0`.

I also provide a "short title" for the running header; surely your publisher isn't forcing you to provide the full chapter name in that space as well.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{book} % 12pt is a manuscript requirement.
% I am using the following three packages with pdflatex.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[top=3.0in,head=2.0in,inner=2.0in,outer=1.0in,
     bottom=1.0in,nofoot]{geometry} % Manuscript requirement.
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % Manuscript requirement.
\usepackage{microtype} % Provides ligature disabling in pdflatex 
    (manuscript requirement) among other things.
\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding=T1} % Manuscript requirement.
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e} % Manuscript requirement.
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace} % Manuscript requirement.
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tgheros} % The font that I intend to use.
\sloppy % Helps package hyphenat.
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{50\p@}{0\p@}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vskip 20\p@}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{german}
\renewcommand*{\chaptername}{\textnumero{}}
\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{592}
\chapter[Kleiner Ärger]{>>Kleiner Ärger --- vom Mantel der Zufriedenheit 
   überdeckt<< (Beweise für die Unmenschlichkeit und Verlogenheit der 
   >>Arbeiter<<-Annonce in >>Welt<< und >>Spiegel<<) (von~Schnitzler, 
   2.~August~1971)}

\textlangle{}Text\textrangle{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I agree, this solution is quite reasonable, especially since the later editions of the Chicago Manual of Style no long insist on dropped chapter headings.  Thank you!