# Breaks Long title in chapter headers into 2 lines

Tags: header-footer, book-design

I used `book` class to write my thesis as follows

```
\documentclass [12pt,oneside,final]{book}
```

The title of some chapters are long so it reaches the page number as shown in picture.

how I can breaks Long titles of the chapter in the headers into 2 lines so it will look better

any idea
[image]

Comment: It would be a far better idea to follow some of the guidelines in [How can I display a short chapter name in the header and a long chapter name in the ToC?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6862/5764)

Comment: You can also use fancyhdr to put a    \parbox into the header.  You might need to change    \headheight.

Comment: Werner's suggestion is best. An improvement (typographically) on the `fancyhdr` suggestion would be to alter the headers/footers in another way e.g. use a smaller font, put the page number in the footer etc.