# Page setup in memoir class

Tags: spacing, header-footer, memoir

I have been using the memoir class based template for sometime. All this while I have been having a problem with the top margin of the document.

Following is the pagestyle code

```
\settypeblocksize{*}{32pc}{1.618}

\setlrmargins{*}{1.47in}{*}

\setulmargins{*}{*}{1.3}

\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip}
\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*}

\def\baselinestretch{1.5}

\checkandfixthelayout
```

The picture of the top margin is given below

[image]

How to push the text about 2.5cm from the top edge?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Such a code snippet is not sufficient to reproduce the behavior. Can you please turn it into a minimal compilable example?

Comment: This has a good solution for specifying separate titles for the TOC, header, and the chapter title: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/how-can-i-display-a-short-chapter-name-in-the-header-and-a-long-chapter-name-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your page design is too crowded, as the warning shows:

```
Overfull \vbox (12.0pt too high) has occurred while \output is active [2]

Class memoir Warning: The material used in the headers is too large
(24.0pt) for the given head height (12.0pt), it is recommended to
either increase the head height or redesign the header
(in both cases you will find help in the memoir manual). on input line 14.
```

While, technically, your use of `\settypeblocksize` and `\setulmargins` is impeccable, the end result (I did this on A4 stock and page size) is that there isn't enough space in the header to accomodate your long title.

There are a number of different ways to fix this, most of which will change the proportions of the typeblock, which, I recognise, you may not want to do.

However, since a long title in the page header probably isn't essential, you might want to try using a short title for the header and TOC:

```
\chapter[Shorter Title]{{Lalala lalala lalala lalala 
lalala lalala lalala lalala lalala lalala lalala lalala lalala lalala}}
```

If you need the long title in the TOC, then something like this will work, but is rather brittle:

```
\chapter{Lalala lalala lalala lalala lalala lalala 
lalala lalala lalala lalala lalala lalala lalala lalala}
\markboth{Short chapter title}{}
```

Comment: I actually did what you suggested and submitted my work about 2 months ago :D. I kept the question open to see any other answers or suggestions and partly I forgot about it. Thank you for taking time to answer my Q

Comment: This has a good solution for specifying separate titles for the TOC, header, and the chapter title: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/how-can-i-display-a-short-chapter-name-in-the-header-and-a-long-chapter-name-in

Answer (score 0):

I use your code and `lipsum` package. I have no errors and looks like

[image]

but with long chapter name ocurrs like your picture. Review your header config.

Comment: I have a similar problem, with an unmodified memoir and long chapter titles. in this case, the text "chapter 1" is not essential, because the book are not really numbered chapters. is there an easy way to get rid of "chapter" plus number and just have the chapter title (short title).

Comment: In that case there's no problems. Indeed you can "play" with the size font of the title ...

Comment: but how can I change the header to show only the chapter title, without "chapter N:" prefixed?

Comment: You can try with `titleps` package ...

Comment: Or you can use `\markboth{Title of the chapter}{}` just after the `\chapter{Title of the chapter}` and using `\leftmark` in the header

Answer (score 0):

I think the real issue here is `\setulmargins` -- you're not using it to specify a defined top margin, which is what your question is asking for. From the memoir manual, the syntax is `\setulmargins{⟨upper⟩}{⟨lower⟩}{⟨ratio⟩}` -- where `<upper>` and `<lower>` are your desired margins. By calling `\setulmargins{*}{*}{1.3}` you're actually explicitly telling memoir to maintain a page aspect ratio of 1.3 according to the formula U+L= Constant = P_h - B_h, where U and L are the upper and lower entered above, P_h is the height of the page and B_h is the height of the block.

If you want a defined upper margin of 2.5 cm, just type in `\setulmargins{2.5 cm}{*}{*}` instead.