# Page numbers incl. text (different side)

Tags: header-footer, margins, page-numbering, classicthesis, thesis

I have two questions according to my Thesis. First, how do I switch margins automatically for every second pages, such as:

[image]
[image]

Second how do I switch the page numbers and including different text every second pages?

[image]
[image]

If anyone could help me by doing that, I would appreciate it!

Best regards

Comment: I've only one question: Can show us a MWE ?;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually similar to the style I'm using in my thesis. I'm not sure I understood what you mean with "switch margins", but Latex should arrange the margins in a `twoside` document automatically. If you want to add further space, you can use the option `bindingoffset` of the `geometry` package (you only need to change the `0mm` in the code below).

To change the footers (and headers) of the page I used the `fancyhdr` package; i redefined also the `plain` style to keep consistency throughout the document.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

% Page layout
\usepackage[bindingoffset=0mm]{geometry}

% Random text
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Page style
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Defining the DEFAULT style
\fancypagestyle{MyStyle}{%
\fancyhead{} %Clean headers
\fancyfoot{} %Clean footers
\fancyfoot[RO]{\leftmark \ {\vrule height 13pt width 1pt}  \thepage}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage \ {\vrule height 13pt width 1pt} \MakeUppercase{\chaptername}\ \thechapter}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove header rule
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\uppercase{##1}}{}}
}
% Redefining the PLAIN style
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{} %Clean headers
\fancyfoot{} %Clean footers
\fancyfoot[RO]{{\vrule height 13pt width 1pt} \ \thepage}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage \ {\vrule height 13pt width 1pt}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove header rule
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
...pages in plain style...
\pagestyle{MyStyle}
\chapter{First chapter title}
\section{First section}
\lipsum
\section{Second section}
\lipsum
\chapter{Second chapter title}
\section{Third section}
\lipsum
\section{Fourth section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

One thing I noticed is that `MyStyle` is applied correctly only if there is a previous `\pagestyle{plain}`; I'm not sure of why this happens, but luckily there are always pages in plain style before the chapters (at least in my thesis), like table of contents, list of figure, etc.

Comment: I will try working on that. Thank you so much. Is it possible, that I can see your thesis and your LaTeX-commands? I am using MinionPro. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to see my page style you can look at this question I asked: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250232/fancyhdr-does-not-apply-the-right-style. That is more or less the style I am using. Moreover, I only used  `titlesec` to increase the blank space before the chapter title.

Comment: I have two questions @MarcoG. If I only want to keep the different in footnote. And if I want to use "article" instead of "report" how should I make the different?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand your first question. Regarding the second one, the `documentclass{article}` doesn't include chapters, therefore you can't use this style. You could add the section title redefing `\rightmark` in this way: `\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\uppercase{##1}}{}}` and changing the footer's style with `\fancyfoot[RO]{\rightmark \ {\vrule height 13pt width 1pt}  \thepage}`.

Comment: Page 1 doesn't show "Introduction" or "Chapter One". Do you know why? And how do I increase/decrease the space between the page number and the "Introduction" or "Chapter One"? Finally how do I change the text format? Thank you!

Comment: So it looks more like the attached photo above

Comment: @A.F. You're welcome! The initial page of each chapter is in `plain` style by default; to modify it, you have to redifine this style (as I did). If you want to add "Chapter 1", for example, you only need `\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage \ {\vrule height 13pt width 1pt} \MakeUppercase{\chaptername}\ \thechapter}` (in the `plain` style). To change the distance between the rule and the text, you could use `\hspace{<distance>}` between `{\vrule...}` and the text. Finally, to change the format, it is the same as changing the format inside the body of the document: e.g. `\textbf{\leftmark}`.

Comment: If I want to change size - I just put \small in before \MakeUppercase{\chaptername}? On my first page it don't show the chapter name or title of the chapter. How do I change that? Finally, if I have a chaptername like: "Study 3: What is the difference between X and X". Instead of putting the whole chaptername into page numbers, how do I only take a part of the, for instance: "Study 3"?

Comment: @A.F. `\small{\MakeUppercase{...}}` works fine. By first page, do you mean the initial page of a chapter? If so, then you basically have to copy the code of `MyStyle` inside the `plain` redefinition (but in this way you will change all your plain pages). To remove a part of the chapter title, you could use `\chapter[Short title]{Long title}`, but you'll have `Short title` also in `toc`; to avoid this, you can write `\chapter{Long title} \chaptermark{Short title}` (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/how-can-i-display-a-short-chapter-name-in-the-header-and-a-long-chapter-name-in-t)

Comment: Weird. It works fine here now as well. The chaptermark was exactly my missing point. On the first I can only see the page number. On every other pages I can see the page number and chaptername or chapter. I just want to know if it is possible to start seeing a page number and chaptername or chapter from the first page? If that makes sense.

Comment: @A.F.You see only the page number and no text in every first page of chapters. That happens because `plain` style is applied, instead of `MyStyle`. If you copy the code inside `\fancypagestyle{MyStyle}{...}` in `\fancypagestyle{plain}{...}`, you'll get the same footer in every page. But usually this is not recommended, since in the initial pages you can see chapter's number and title easily, and the footer would be useless; moreover, you'll have many `plain` pages inside your document (first page of table of contents, etc), and changing this style will affect them all.

Comment: Your help has been amazing - I just still have one more questions about the footer. I have therefore created a new question, which I hope you could help me with!

Comment: @A.F. You're welcome :-) ! I could not look at your question during the past days, but I saw that you got already an answer!

Comment: Hi MarcoG. I have tried cfr's solution, but it won't work together with your command. If I would like to make it possible to have chapter/chaptername in the first part. And only bibliography/bibliography and appendix/appendix in the footer in the last part - what should I edited?