# Fancyhdr does not apply the right style

Tags: fancyhdr, thesis

I am using Latex for the first time, to write my thesis.

I organized my work as a main file that calls several others using `subfiles`, since I like to compile a single chapter while I am working on it. However, the chapters produced in this way do not have the same layout of the main file (this is a problem only for the final version, that I have to send to my supervisor).
I overcame this problem compiling the main file with all the code commented but the one necessary to produce the chapter I an intersted in, and changing `\setcounter{chapter}{}` in order to have the right number.

It works fine, but I saw that if I comment `\pagestyle{plain}` in the code below, the package `fancyhdr` does not apply the page style I defined. May someone explain me why? I expected that since I entered `\pagestyle{MyStyle}` then the style of the pages following this command should be `MyStyle`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

% Page layout
\usepackage[a4paper,
            inner=41mm,
            outer=32mm,
            top=43mm,
            bottom=44mm,
            headheight=20pt,
            headsep=\baselineskip,
            bindingoffset=0mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{emptypage}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{subfiles}

% Page style
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% Defining MyStyle
\fancypagestyle{MyStyle}{%
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark \ \ {\vrule height 13pt width 1pt} \ \textbf{\thepage}}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\textbf{\thepage} \ {\vrule height 13pt width 1pt} \ \leftmark}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter. \ \textsc{##1}}{}}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ {##1}}}
}
% Redefining the PLAIN style
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyhead[RO]{{\vrule height 13pt width 1pt} \ \textbf{\thepage}}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\textbf{\thepage} \ {\vrule height 13pt width 1pt}}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\pagestyle{plain}

%Abstract

%Table of Contents

%Lists of Figures

%Lists of Tables

\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{MyStyle}

% Previous chapters...

\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\chapter{Chapter Title}
\section{First section title}
\lipsum
\section{Second section title}
\lipsum

% Following chapters...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe if you add `\pagestyle{}` before apply your page style could woks: `\usepackage{fancyhdr} \pagestyle{} \fancypagestyle...`

Comment: It's possible to switch temporarily to `\pagestyle{plain}` within `\fancypagestyle{MyStyle}`, before the changes are made

Comment: To be honest, i don't see anything strange looking at your output. With or without `plain` commented.

Comment: If `\tableofcontents` is used without `\pagestyle{plain}` the whole stuff works too. I assume that it has something to do with the effective non-page right at the beginning of the document

Comment: I believe \tableofcontents activates \thispagestyle{empty}.  Anyway, aren't you supposed to use \pagestyle{fancy} with fancyhdr?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I think that `\pagestyle{MyStyle}` is the same as `\pagestyle{fancy}`, but it applies the style I defined and not the default one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the package manual section 9 "The scoop on LATEX’s marks" (page 9):

> You can influence how chapter, section, and subsection information
>   (only two of them!) is displayed by redefining the \chaptermark,
>   \sectionmark, and \subsectionmark commands. You must put the
>   redefinition after the first call of \pagestyle{fancy} as this sets up
>   the defaults.

More specifically the first call of \ps@fancy sets the defaults.

The definition of `\fancypagestyle` (from the `fancyhdr.sty`):

```
\newcommand{\fancypagestyle}[2]{%
  \@namedef{ps@#1}{\let\fancy@gbl\relax#2\relax\ps@fancy}}
```

Note that `\fancypagestyle{MyStyle}` is not executed until the first call of `\pagestyle{MyStyle}` is done. So if the `\pagestyle{MyStyle}` is the first call of a fancyhdr pagestyle it is also the first call of `\ps@fancy`. Hence the redefinitions of `\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark` in the second argument of `\fancypagestyle` are overwritten by the defaults. But if you call an other fancyhdr pagestyle before `MyStyle` or you use `\pagestyle{MyStyle}` again it works fine.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Page style
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}% <- !
% Defining MyStyle
\fancypagestyle{MyStyle}{%
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark \ \ {\vrule height 13pt width 1pt} \ \textbf{\thepage}}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\textbf{\thepage} \ {\vrule height 13pt width 1pt} \ \leftmark}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter. \ \textsc{##1}}{}}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ {##1}}}
}
% Redefining the PLAIN style
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyhead[RO]{{\vrule height 13pt width 1pt} \ \textbf{\thepage}}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\textbf{\thepage} \ {\vrule height 13pt width 1pt}}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{MyStyle}
% Previous chapters...
\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\chapter{Chapter Title}
\section{First section title}
\lipsum
\section{Second section title}
\lipsum
% Following chapters...
\end{document}
```

It is also possible to use

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Page style
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Defining MyStyle
\fancypagestyle{MyStyle}{%
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark \ \ {\vrule height 13pt width 1pt} \ \textbf{\thepage}}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\textbf{\thepage} \ {\vrule height 13pt width 1pt} \ \leftmark}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter. \ \textsc{##1}}{}}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ {##1}}}
}
% Redefining the PLAIN style
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyhead[RO]{{\vrule height 13pt width 1pt} \ \textbf{\thepage}}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\textbf{\thepage} \ {\vrule height 13pt width 1pt}}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{MyStyle}% or \pagestyle{fancy} or \pagestyle{plain}
\pagestyle{MyStyle}
% Previous chapters...
\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\chapter{Chapter Title}
\section{First section title}
\lipsum
\section{Second section title}
\lipsum
% Following chapters...
\end{document}
```

Note that `\pagestyle{plain}\pagestyle{MyStyle}` only works if `plain` is redefined by `\fancypagestyle{plain}{...}`.

---

Additionally here is another suggestion using `scrlayer-scrpage`

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Page style
\usepackage[automark,markcase=noupper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\bfseries}
\providepairofpagestyles{MyStyle}{
  \rohead%
    [{\vrule height 13pt width 1pt} \ \pagemark]%
    {\headmark \ \ {\vrule height 13pt width 1pt} \ \pagemark}
  \lehead%
    [\pagemark \ {\vrule height 13pt width 1pt}]%
    {\pagemark \ {\vrule height 13pt width 1pt} \ \scshape{\headmark}}
  \renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{\thechapter. \ }
}
\DeclarePageStyleAlias{plain}{plain.MyStyle}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{MyStyle}
% Previous chapters...
\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\chapter{Chapter Title}
\section{First section title}
\lipsum
\section{Second section title}
\lipsum
% Following chapters...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now everything is clear, I must have missed that line when I read the `fancyhdr` package!