# Remove Zero as Chapter Number in Header Using scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: tikz-pgf, table-of-contents, header-footer, numbering, scrlayer-scrpage

I am currently working on a layout for a document (based on [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423091/chapter-heading-designs-in-koma-script) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272824/pagenumbers-headers-with-vertical-lines-style)), using scrbook with scrlayer-scrpage.

After a long struggle to get lines with rounded corners in the header and footer, everything works as expected -- except the numbering of the table of contents in the header. For some reason that I do not understand (I am sure because lack of basic knowledge) it gets a chapter number 0 and section number 0.0, instead of an empty field, which is the desired output for unnumbered chapters.

When I compile my document with the slightly modified [original code for the header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272824/pagenumbers-headers-with-vertical-lines-style) no numbers are given for the table of contents.

Based on this, my idea was to use `\ifnumbered{chapter}{THEN}{ELSE}`, either by redefining `\chaptermarkformat` and `\sectionmarkformat` (IDEA 1) or by changing the output for `\lehead{}` (and `\rohead{}` IDEA 2). What am I missing? Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Here is the code containing my approaches and the modified original code for the header and footer for camparison:

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4,DIV=calc,parskip=off,numbers=noenddot,chapterprefix=false]{scrbook} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[inner=1.5cm,outer=3.0cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,headheight=8mm,headsep=1cm,footskip=1cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry} % ,showframe
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{2.77cm}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{.2cm}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

% Chapter Title Layout -------------------------------------------------
% BASED ON: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423091/chapter-heading-designs-in-koma-script
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, backgrounds}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
    \contourlength{1.25pt}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\raggedright}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\Huge}
\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\LARGE}
\newkomafont{chapternumber}{\bfseries\fontsize{75pt}{75pt}\selectfont}

\tikzset{
    headings/base/.style = {
        outer sep = 0pt,
        inner sep = 0pt,
        %draw, rectangle    % just for testing purposes
    },
    headings/chapterbackground/.style = {
        headings/base,
        % if shades are to be used (gave ugly results for the shading):
        %      shade,
        %      left color = white,
        %      right color = black,
        % without shades:
        color = black
    },
    headings/chapapp/.style = {
        headings/base,
        text = black,
        font = \usekomafont{chapterprefix}
    },
    headings/chapternumber/.style= { 
        headings/base,
        text = black,
        font = \usekomafont{chapternumber}
    }
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
    \ifstr{#1}{chapter}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(title.base)]
        \node[headings/base,anchor=center](title){%
            \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth\relax}            
            {\parbox[t][\height]{\dimexpr\textwidth\relax}{\raggedchapter{#3}}\strut}% {\raggedchapter{\leavevmode\vphantom{\textbf{Ôp'}}#3}} //orig: {\raggedchapter #3}
        };
        % chapter number
        \ifstr{#2}{}
        {   % a phantom chapternumber is set to achieve the same vertical spacing for toc and other unnumbered chapters as for numbered chapters
            \node(chapternumber)[anchor=south west,headings/chapternumber]
            at([yshift=-14.5pt] title.north east){\leavevmode\vphantom{88}};%
            \fill[headings/base,anchor=north west,rounded corners=2.5 pt]
            ([xshift=4 pt]chapternumber.north west)
            rectangle
            ([yshift=-7 pt,xshift=.33\marginparwidth+4 pt]chapternumber.north west);%
            \fill[headings/base,color=black!85,anchor=north west,rounded corners=2.5 pt]
            ([yshift=-9 pt,xshift=5.5pt]chapternumber.north west)
            rectangle
            ([yshift=-16 pt,xshift=.33\marginparwidth+5.5pt]chapternumber.north west);%
            \fill[headings/base,color=black!70,anchor=north west,rounded corners=2.5 pt]
            ([yshift=-18 pt,xshift=9pt]chapternumber.north west)
            rectangle
            ([yshift=-25 pt,xshift=.33\marginparwidth+9pt]chapternumber.north west);%
            \fill[headings/base,color=black!50,anchor=north west,rounded corners=2.5 pt]
            ([yshift=-27 pt,xshift=16.5pt]chapternumber.north west)
            rectangle
            ([yshift=-34 pt,xshift=.33\marginparwidth+16.5pt]chapternumber.north west);%
            \fill[headings/base,color=black!20,anchor=north west,rounded corners=2.5 pt]
            ([yshift=-36 pt,xshift=30pt]chapternumber.north west)
            rectangle
            ([yshift=-43 pt,xshift=.33\marginparwidth+30pt]chapternumber.north west);%
            \fill[headings/base,color=black!10,anchor=north west,rounded corners=2.5 pt]
            ([yshift=-45 pt,xshift=52pt]chapternumber.north west)
            rectangle
            ([yshift=-52 pt,xshift=.33\marginparwidth+52pt]chapternumber.north west);%
        }
        {   % number definition for numbered chapters
            \node(chapternumber)[anchor=south west,headings/chapternumber]
            at([yshift=-14.5pt] title.north east){#2};%
        }
        % decorative element(s)
        \ifstr{#2}{}{}{
            \fill[headings/chapterbackground,anchor=east,rounded corners=1 pt]
            ([yshift=11.5 pt]title.north east)
            rectangle
            ([yshift=13.5 pt,xshift=4.2 cm]title.north);%
        }
        % chapter prefix
        \node(chapapp)[headings/chapapp,anchor=north east]
        at (chapternumber.north west){\ifstr{#2}{}{\leavevmode\vphantom{\contour{white}\chapapp}}{\contour{white}\chapapp}\strut};% 
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \par
    }{%
        \@hangfrom{#2}{#3}% other section levels using style=chapter
    }%
}
\makeatother

% Header and Footer Layout --------------------------------
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\footnotesize}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\sffamily\normalsize}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily\large}
\clearpairofpagestyles

    \newlength{\vrulewidth}
        \setlength{\vrulewidth}{1.25 pt}

    \renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{%
        \markboth{\ifnumbered{chapter}{#1}{#1}}{\ifnumbered{chapter}{#1}{#1}}%
    }

    % IDEA 1: Supposed to remove chapternumber from header in table of contents -- does not
%   \renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{%
%       \ifnumbered{chapter}{\chapappifchapterprefix{\ }\thechapter\autodot\enskip}{}% taken from scrguide
%   }

    \renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{%
        \markright{\ifnumbered{section}{#1}{#1}}%
    }

    % IDEA 1 (part 2): Supposed to remove sectionumber from header in table of contents -- does not
%   \renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{%
%       \ifnumbered{section}{\thesection\autodot\enskip}{}% taken from scrguide
%   }

\lehead{%
%   \ifnumbered{chapter}{% IDEA 2: Supposed to remove chapternumber from header in table of contents -- does not
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \fill[headings/base,color=black,anchor=south east,rounded corners=0.5\vrulewidth]
    ([xshift=-\marginparsep+.5\vrulewidth] current page header area.south west)
    rectangle
    ([xshift=-\marginparsep-.5\vrulewidth,yshift=\baselineskip] current page header area.south west);
    \node[headings/base,anchor=south east] at ([xshift=-2\marginparsep] current page header area.south west){\ifnumbered{chapter}{\leavevmode\vphantom{\headmark\strut}\chaptermarkformat}{\leavevmode\vphantom{\headmark\strut}}};
    \node[headings/base,anchor=south west] at (current page header area.south west){\headmark\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}
%   }%  IDEA 2 (part 2)
%   {%
%       \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
%           \fill[headings/base,color=black,anchor=south east,rounded corners=0.5\vrulewidth]
%           ([xshift=-\marginparsep+.5\vrulewidth] current page header area.south west)
%           rectangle
%           ([xshift=-\marginparsep-.5\vrulewidth,yshift=\baselineskip] current page header area.south west);
%%          \node[headings/base,anchor=south east] at ([xshift=-2\marginparsep] current page header area.south west){\ifnumbered{chapter}{\leavevmode\vphantom{\headmark\strut}\chaptermarkformat}{\leavevmode\vphantom{\headmark\strut}}};
%           \node[headings/base,anchor=south west] at (current page header area.south west){\headmark\strut};
%       \end{tikzpicture}
%   }
}

\rohead{% (IDEA 2 did not work for \lehead)
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \fill[headings/base,color=black,anchor=south west,rounded corners=0.5\vrulewidth]
        ([xshift=\marginparsep-.5\vrulewidth] current page header area.south east)
        rectangle
        ([xshift=\marginparsep+.5\vrulewidth,yshift=\baselineskip] current page header area.south east);
        \node[headings/base,anchor=south west] at ([xshift=2\marginparsep] current page header area.south east){\ifnumbered{section}{\leavevmode\vphantom{\headmark\strut}\sectionmarkformat}{\leavevmode\vphantom{\headmark\strut}}};
        \node[headings/base,anchor=south east] at (current page header area.south east){\headmark\strut};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\lefoot*{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \fill[headings/base,color=black,anchor=south east,rounded corners=0.5\vrulewidth]
        ([xshift=-\marginparsep+.5\vrulewidth] current page footer area.south west)
        rectangle
        ([xshift=-\marginparsep-.5\vrulewidth,yshift=-3\baselineskip] current page footer area.south west);
        \node[headings/base,anchor=south east] at ([xshift=-2\marginparsep,yshift=-3\baselineskip] current page footer area.south west){\pagemark\strut};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\rofoot*{% funktioniert ohne * nur auf nicht chapter-Seiten
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \fill[headings/base,color=black,anchor=south west,rounded corners=0.5\vrulewidth]
        ([xshift=\marginparsep-.5\vrulewidth] current page footer area.south east)
        rectangle
        ([xshift=\marginparsep+.5\vrulewidth,yshift=-3\baselineskip] current page footer area.south east);
        \node[headings/base,anchor=south west] at ([xshift=2\marginparsep,yshift=-3\baselineskip] current page footer area.south east){\pagemark\strut};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272824/pagenumbers-headers-with-vertical-lines-style
    %% here there are no numbers for the table of contents in the headings -- numbering in TOC as desired
%   \renewcommand*{\chaptermark}[1]{% 
%       \markboth{% 
%           \makebox[0pt][r]{%
%               \ifnumbered{chapter}{%
%                   \chaptermarkformat% Kapitelnummer 
%                   %\enskip% Abstand -- wird zu groß, wenn nicht auskommentiert
%                   \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\vrulewidth}{\baselineskip}% Linie -- Offset,Breite,Höhe
%                   \hspace*{\marginparsep}% Abstand
%               }{}%
%           }% 
%           #1% Text 
%       }{%
%           #1%Text 
%           \makebox[0pt][l]{%
%               \hspace*{\marginparsep}% Abstand 
%               \ifnumbered{chapter}{%
%                   \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\vrulewidth}{\baselineskip}% Linie -- Offset,Breite,Höhe
%                   \enskip% Abstand 
%                   \chaptermarkformat% Kapitelnummer
%               }{}%
%           }% 
%       }% 
%   } 
%   \renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{% 
%       \markright{% 
%           #1%Text 
%           \makebox[0pt][l]{% 
%               \ifnumbered{section}{%
%                   \hspace{\marginparsep}% Abstand 
%                   \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\vrulewidth}{\baselineskip}% Linie -- Offset,Breite,Höhe
%                   \enskip% Abstand 
%                   \sectionmarkformat% Abschnittsnummer 
%               }{}%
%           }% 
%       }% 
%   } 
%   \ohead{\headmark} 
%   \rofoot*{%
%       \makebox[0pt][l]{%
%           \hspace{\marginparsep}%  
%           \raisebox{0pt}[\ht\strutbox][\dp\strutbox]{% 
%               \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\vrulewidth}{2\baselineskip}% Linie -- Offset,Breite,Höhe
%           }% 
%           \enskip 
%           \pagemark 
%       }% 
%   }
%   \lefoot*{%
%       \makebox[0pt][r]{% 
%           \pagemark 
%           \enskip
%           \raisebox{0pt}[\ht\strutbox][\dp\strutbox]{% 
%               \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\vrulewidth}{2\baselineskip}% Linie -- Offset,Breite,Höhe 
%           }% 
%           \hspace{\marginparsep}%
%       }% 
%   }

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[raiselinks,colorlinks,bookmarks,pageanchor,hyperindex]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=RoyalBlue}

\begin{document}
    \markboth{Inhaltsverzeichnis}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
        \tableofcontents
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
    \clearpage
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
        \Blinddocument
        \Blinddocument
        \Blinddocument
        \Blinddocument
        \Blinddocument
        \Blinddocument
        \Blinddocument
        \Blinddocument
        \Blinddocument
    \appendix
        \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Edit: here are some images to visualize the differences:
[image: original Chapter lehead]
[image: original Chapter rohead]
[image: original TOC lehead]
[image: original TOC rohead]
[image: Chapter Start]
[image: TOC Start]
[image: Chapter lehead -- intended output]
[image: Chapter rohead -- intended output]
[image: TOC lehead -- unwanted number]
[image: TOC rohead -- unwanted number]

**EDIT:** I just figured out ([here](https://texwelt.de/fragen/7758/koma-script-ifnumbered-fur-kopfzeile-bei-verwendung-von-addchap)) that the problem is that `\ifnumbered{chapter}` checks the value of secnumdepth which is not altered in the header, as far as I understood, and a redefinition of chaptermark is needed. My redefinition is obviously not enough for the intended result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that merges the original `\rule` based approach with tikzpictures. I left the original parts as comments. I am still wondering if there is a fully tikz-based approach, though.

```
    \renewcommand*{\chaptermark}[1]{% 
        \markboth{% 
            \makebox[0pt][r]{%
                \ifnumbered{chapter}{%
                    \chaptermarkformat% Kapitelnummer 
                    %\enskip% Abstand -- wird zu groß, wenn nicht auskommentiert
%                   \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\vrulewidth}{\baselineskip}% Linie -- Offset,Breite,Höhe
                    \hspace*{\marginparsep}% Abstand
                }{}%
            }% 
            #1% Text 
        }{%
            #1%Text 
            \makebox[0pt][l]{%
                \hspace*{2\marginparsep}% Abstand 
                \ifnumbered{chapter}{%
%                   \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\vrulewidth}{\baselineskip}% Linie -- Offset,Breite,Höhe
%                   \enskip% Abstand 
                    \chaptermarkformat% Kapitelnummer
                }{}%
            }% 
        }% 
    } 
    \renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{% 
        \markright{% 
            #1%Text 
            \makebox[0pt][l]{% 
                \ifnumbered{section}{%
                    \hspace{2\marginparsep}% Abstand 
%                   \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\vrulewidth}{\baselineskip}% Linie -- Offset,Breite,Höhe
%                   \enskip% Abstand 
                    \sectionmarkformat% Abschnittsnummer 
                }{}%
            }% 
        }% 
    }

\lehead{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
            \fill[headings/base,color=black,anchor=south east,rounded corners=0.5\vrulewidth]
            ([xshift=-\marginparsep+.5\vrulewidth] current page header area.south west)
            rectangle
            ([xshift=-\marginparsep-.5\vrulewidth,yshift=\baselineskip] current page header area.south west);
%           \node[headings/base,anchor=south east] at ([xshift=-2\marginparsep] current page header area.south west){\leavevmode\vphantom{\headmark\strut}\chaptermarkformat};
            \node[headings/base,anchor=south west] at (current page header area.south west){\headmark\strut};
        \end{tikzpicture}
}
\rohead{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \fill[headings/base,color=black,anchor=south west,rounded corners=0.5\vrulewidth]
        ([xshift=\marginparsep-.5\vrulewidth] current page header area.south east)
        rectangle
        ([xshift=\marginparsep+.5\vrulewidth,yshift=\baselineskip] current page header area.south east);
%       \node[headings/base,anchor=south west] at ([xshift=2\marginparsep] current page header area.south east){\leavevmode\vphantom{\headmark\strut}\sectionmarkformat};
        \node[headings/base,anchor=south east] at (current page header area.south east){\headmark\strut};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\lefoot*{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \fill[headings/base,color=black,anchor=south east,rounded corners=0.5\vrulewidth]
        ([xshift=-\marginparsep+.5\vrulewidth] current page footer area.south west)
        rectangle
        ([xshift=-\marginparsep-.5\vrulewidth,yshift=-3\baselineskip] current page footer area.south west);
        \node[headings/base,anchor=south east] at ([xshift=-2\marginparsep,yshift=-3\baselineskip] current page footer area.south west){\pagemark\strut};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\rofoot*{% funktioniert ohne * nur auf nicht chapter-Seiten
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \fill[headings/base,color=black,anchor=south west,rounded corners=0.5\vrulewidth]
        ([xshift=\marginparsep-.5\vrulewidth] current page footer area.south east)
        rectangle
        ([xshift=\marginparsep+.5\vrulewidth,yshift=-3\baselineskip] current page footer area.south east);
        \node[headings/base,anchor=south west] at ([xshift=2\marginparsep,yshift=-3\baselineskip] current page footer area.south east){\pagemark\strut};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```