# Modify the header in a document - Header out of margins

Tags: header-footer

I need to modify the header for this chapter but avoiding modifications in other chapters and the  ToC.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Integración del MCC con herramientas de Gestión de Mantenimiento Asistido por Computadora}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The "issue"

[image]

Comment: Use the optional argument of `\chapter` like `\chapter[Integración del MCC ]{Integración del MCC con herramientas de Gestión de Mantenimiento Asistido por Computadora}`  Give optional argument a short title.

Comment: @HarishKumar That will change it in the ToC, too, won't it?

Comment: @cfr: certainly. Better way is to give a sensible short title. Long titles look ugly in TOC too, IMO. :)

Comment: @HarishKumar Oh, I agree. I was merely pointing out that it does not actually do what is asked here. And the OP might not get to decide how this goes - formatting requirements are sometimes far from sane, as we all know.

Answer (score 0):

As Mr. Kumar said in comments, using the optional arguments does the trick and, even when @cfr is right (This solution modify the ToC as well),  I'm agree with "Long titles look bad in ToC".

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter[Integracion del MCC con herramientas GMAC]{Integración del MCC con herramientas de Gestión de Mantenimiento Asistido por Computadora}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Results:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

### EDIT

The answer posted in

[How can I display a short chapter name in the header and a long chapter name in the ToC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/how-can-i-display-a-short-chapter-name-in-the-header-and-a-long-chapter-name-in)

Works perfect