# One line header for two line section

Tags: header-footer, line-breaking, fancyhdr

In my code I have two line sections.
But I want it in 1 line in header .
What can I do?

```
\documentclass{biditufte-handout}
\usepackage{ptext}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}
\reversemarginpar


\begin{document} 
\section{یک عنوان \\ بخش}
\ptext[1]
\end{document}
```

This picture is my goal:
[image: This is my goal]

Comment: related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/how-can-i-display-a-short-chapter-name-in-the-header-and-a-long-chapter-name-in

Comment: use the optional argument of section: `\section[line line]{line \\ line}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supply the header as the optional argument

```
\section[abc def]{abc \\ def}
```

Comment: Tanks.
for youre answer and your speed!