# In a custom documentclass, maintain chapter title headings but move page numbers to bottom

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, document-classes, documentclass-writing

I am using a custom documentclass provided by my school for writing my thesis, which is a modification of the documentclass book. They also give a template, which includes the line

```
\pagestyle{headings}
```

When this is activated, each page (that doesn't begin a chapter) has the chapter title across the top, and the page number at the top right. When the chapter title is long, it runs right into the page number, even overlapping it. When this is deactivated, I lose the entire heading, including the chapter title and page number.

I am aware of ways of overriding the documentclass file such as by specifying a different pagestyle (such as plain or fancy), but these also override my header.

I want to keep the chapter titles at the top of the page, but move the page number to the bottom. Do I need to edit the documentclass file, or is there a way to just redefine what "headings" does?

I know nothing about writing documentclass files but my guess is that I can get the desired effect by altering a portion of it that looks like this:

```
 \def\ps@headings{%
      \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
      \def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
      \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
      \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\chaptermark##1{%
      \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
          \if@mainmatter
            \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
          \fi
        \fi
        ##1}}{}}%
    \def\sectionmark##1{%
      \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
          \thesection. \ %
        \fi
```

Comment: The class that you are using is unknown, but probably there should work an optional argument: `\chapter[short title]{full title}`.

Comment: That does work, and is a great alternative. If it is too involved to move the page numbers I will do this instead.

Comment: Ooh, one thing I don't like about it though is it also changes the title in my table of contents. I'm okay with abbreviating at the top of a page but I prefer to have the full chapter titles in that.

Comment: Also the document class is a modification of "book." I will insert this in the question.

Comment: Maybe this solution: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/how-can-i-display-a-short-chapter-name-in-the-header-and-a-long-chapter-name-in would be useful for you?

Comment: Yes that does make your first suggestion a viable workaround. Perhaps this would be better to do anyway if it is more conventional -- when you're finish a PhD is a bad time to be breaking rules.

Comment: And probably a class provided by your school is a help for those who have problems, not a strict restriction. As in TeX error messages: *maybe you should try asking a human*?

Comment: People can be very picky about formatting for things like theses or job applications. In fact there are aesthetic choices I would make differently on such documents given the freedom. But alas freedom will have to wait.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways. You can patch the original code to place the page number at the bottom. Or patch it to wrap longer chapter tites (example at the bottom). Other ways might be to remove the string *CHAPTER* or to remove all this uppercasing altogether.

All of those are changing the output of the template. Either way, using a package is better than patching low level commands:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ohead{}
\cfoot{\pagemark}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Wombats are cute and cuddly, just like ducks}
\blindtext[3]
\end{document}
```

Wrapping the title:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\tracingpatches
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@evenhead}{\leftmark}{\parbox[t]{.9\linewidth}{\leftmark}}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Wombats are cute and cuddly, just like ducks}
\blindtext[3]
\end{document}
```

[image: j0eq1nnHeaderFooter]