# Chapter names in headers

Tags: header-footer

I am using the book class to typeset a course I am currently taking. However, a chapter has a long name, and it causes the header to look terrible (the name of the chapter crosses the margins of the paper). Any ideas on how to change the chapter name in the header only, so it would look proper?

Comment: Which book template? Do you mean the class `book`? Can you please show us a minimal but working example? However, short (and somehow speculative) answer (because of missing MWE): Use the optional argument of `\chapter`, e.g., `\chapter[short title]{long title}` or see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/how-can-i-display-a-short-chapter-name-in-the-header-and-a-long-chapter-name-in

Comment: You can use the optional argument to chapter to supply a shorter name

Comment: This is just what I need, and it worked perfectly. Thanks!