# Beamer: Use long section titles in ToC but short section titles in headline

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning, titles

In Beamer, I would like to use the long, full section titles in the table of contents, but shortened titles in the headline at the top of the screen (e.g., provided by the CambridgeUS theme). The section titles are defined as follows:

```
\section[short title]{long title}
```

I tried the suggestion at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6866/9789 but it does not work for me. I wonder if it is because I am in Beamer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [image]

Long section names in toc is the default beamer behavior, so just do nothing :)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section[short title]{long title}   
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I realize that at some point I loaded a package - which I no longer need - that changed this default behavior.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz You are awesome. Your answers are always concise and to the point. Thank you