# Change the text size and type in a page header especially if the text is long

Tags: header-footer, books

I am writing a master thesis using the **Book** class, sometimes the name of the chapter is too long so that the section name and chapter name overlaps in the page header. How can I change the text size and the type in the page header?

Are there any solutions rather than changing the text size?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,french,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[left=25mm,right=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3mm}

\pagestyle{fancy}



\begin{document}

\chapter*{Introduction générale}

\lipsum[2-4]

\part{Cerveau et modélisation de l’activité neuronale}
\chapter{Modalités d'exploration de l'activité neuronale}
\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[2-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: [See this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/how-can-i-display-a-short-chapter-name-in-the-header-and-a-long-chapter-name-in/6866)

Comment: What about operations on the text type  (let say bold text)?

Comment: I'm not sure where you are seeking these operations. The modification should generally follow the defaults in effect.  If I put `\chapter[Modalités]{Modalités d'exploration de l'activité neuronale}` the headers no longer collide.  Since this question is now marked as duplicate, I cannot post an example.