# How to change the title of a section in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

In the file I am working on, some lengthy section titles are split up into two lines in the table of contents, with just one word dangling on the second line. Therefore, I would like to redefine the title of the section that appears in the table of contents, while keeping the original section title the same, such that everything fits neatly on one line in the table of contents. Is this possible and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that one can specify an optional short sectioning header? E.g., if you write `\section[Short title]{Very very very very long and tedious title}`, then `Short title` will be used in the table of contents -- and, as usual, `Very very very very long and tedious title` will be used as the section header in the body of the document. Some document classes (such as `memoir` and the KOMA-Script classes) have further facilities for providing optional short sectioning headers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display a short chapter name in the header and a long chapter name in the ToC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/how-can-i-display-a-short-chapter-name-in-the-header-and-a-long-chapter-name-in) Note that while the title of the query refers to chapter-level headers, the solutions apply to `\section`, `subsection`, etc as well.

Comment: Thanks, Mico. I sought for a long time but I could not find a previous question on the topic, although I suspected that there would be one...