# Starred chapter title with no chapter number in either toc or header

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, chapters, starred-version

I am in the same situation as the author of [How can I display a short chapter name in the header and a long chapter name in the TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/how-can-i-display-a-short-chapter-name-in-the-header-and-a-long-chapter-name-in) but, in addition, I also want the starred version for the Epilogue: no chapter number anywhere.

Here is a MWE:

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Un El\'ephant}

\c ca trompe,

\chapter{Deux El\'ephants}

\c ca trompent, 

\newpage

\c ca trompent, 

\chapter{Trois El\'ephants}

\c ca trompent ...

\newpage

 ... \'enorm\'ement. 

\chapter*[SpryRogue]{Epilogue}\chaptermark{PiLog}             

\newpage

Pas trop n'en faut. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Search for addcontentsline

Comment: *Unrelated* : The default  input encoding has been changed to utf8, and ifyou use T1 font encoding, you'll have  no problem directly typing ‘Un éléphant, ça trompe énormément’.

Comment: @Johannes_B I searched for `addcontentsline` but didn't see anything that would explain what to put in `\addcontentsline{toc}{  }{  }` to make `\chapter*[Spry Rogue]{Epilogue}\chaptermark{Pi Log}` work (as it should).

Comment: @Bernard Didn't know. Don't write much in French anymore. Will try it when this is over.

Comment: \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Epilog}

Comment: @Johannes_B TOC: ok BODY: Title is just a big **[** but first line of text is `SpryRogue]Epilogue`  HEADER: ChapNumber is _previous_ ChapNumber instead of No ChapNumber but correct title!

Comment: Perhaps a `\backmatter` declaration is what you are looking for (and use `\chapter` without `*`).

Comment: Starred chapters don't work with optional argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
\backmatter
\chapter[SpryRogue]{Epilogue}\chaptermark{PiLog}
```

Why on earth do you want *three different titles???*

*C'est fou!*

Comment: 1. T'would take too long to tell the---embarrassing---tale. 2. _Complètement fou!_ 3. Les éléphants sont énormément reconnaissants.