How to add text to a summary section?
My question is probably not very clear!
I am writing a summary paper on students.
Each student has a section.
In the section I specify its qualities and results and at the end I put a noted opinion
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode


\documentclass[11pt]{article}  

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\Avis}[1]{
\textbf{Avis=#1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Avis=#1}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{Nom-Prenom1}

\lipsum[2]

\Avis{5}

\section{Nom-Prenom2}

\lipsum[3]

\Avis{8}


\section{Nom-Prenom3}

\lipsum[5]

\Avis{10}


\end{document}

I would like that in the summary we find on the same line
Last name1 first name1: Opinion=8------------------------page no.
Last name2 first name2: Opinion=5------------------------page no.


The sectioning commands of mist classes have an optional argument. So you could use: \section[Last Name1 First Name1: Opinion=8]{Last Name1 First Name1} If your class also provides an optional argument (or even two) is unclear, because you've not shown the class.

Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6862/277964

I use an article class.
I don't want to use the section option, for that I would have to go back, I would prefer to write my opinion at the end of my comments and add it to the summary.
For the moment I "cheat" I put the opinion as the title of the subsection and it appears in the summary.

Please add all relevant information to the question and make the example compile without error. You are ling enough here to know, how to ask good questions. However, I don't see a reason, why not adding the opinion at the beginning instead at the end of the section,

There are a number of ways to do this.  Easiest would be to create a new file like toc or lof and use \addcontentsline to record the data and  \@starttoc in the summary. section.  You will also need a \l@summary or something similar to format each entry. (see \@dottedtocline).

In your original structure, you showed an environment for each student. The code you've just added shows no such environment. Using an environment would make your task a lot easier to implement.

I added a minimal compilable example

Here's a way to do it. A few comments:

one idea was defining a new environment; however using it is clumsy AND for some reason it didn't like an argument, like #3, in its end-part
so I introduced \newcommand\student[4]{% last, first, avis, comments ...
it incorporates cabohah's idea about the sections
in the documents body I show some ways to use it, i.e. by adjusting code formatting
packages: tikz is probably on your system, while simpsons might be missing (just comment out, if you don't want these)
basically you write your normal LaTeX code as parameter #4
if you miss the dots in the TOC, that's no big deal to introduce


\documentclass[11pt]{article}  
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% ~~~ simpsonizing ... ~~~
\usepackage{tikz}       % is probably on your system
\usepackage{simpsons}   % perhaps needs to be installed


% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\student[4]{% last, first, avis, comments
\section[#1, #2: Avis=\ #3]{#1, #2}%
#4%

\textbf{Avis: #3}%
}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
 \clearpage

 \student{Hitchcock}{Alfred}{10}{
Master or horriffic horror secenes. 
 }
 
 \student{Einstein}{Albert}{3}{
    \lipsum[5-6]
 }
 
 % ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \student   {Simpson}
            {Bart}
            {0}
    {
    Do I really need to say more?
    
    \vspace{20pt}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw=red] {You s**k!};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \Bart
 }

\end{document}

